# jquery-dialog cannot make use of jquery-functions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-dialog

I pass some html coming from a get-request to my Jquery-dialog function.

Inside the dialog however I cannot make use of any jquery-functions anymore although I 
have included jquery in the page calling the dialog.

If I include it AGAIN in the dialog's html the dialog's "ok"-button stops to work and all other stuff on the page from which I have called the dialog also does not work anymore after having closed the dialog.

I would expect that having included jquery in the page which calls the dialogue would suffice for the dialogue to have access to jquery but this does not seem to be the case.

Here's the code I have:

dialog.js :

```
var dialogDiv = $(document.createElement('div'));

function myDialogue(content) {
  dialogDiv.html(content);
  dialogDiv.dialog({autoOpen: false, modal: true, buttons: { "ok": function() {
  $(this).dialog("close");
  $(this).dialog("destroy").remove();
} } });
dialogDiv.dialog('open');
dialogDiv.scrollTop(0);
return true;
}
```

call to myDialogue =>

main.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/dialog.js"></script>

$.get("/path/to/controller/index", {param: "value"}, function(content) {
  myDialogue(content);
});
```

the html returned from my controller which is passed to the dialog:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#edit_div :checkbox").click(function () {
    // this NEVER gets called unless I include jquery again, but 
    // then the ok button and the rest of the page do not work anymore.
    alert("checked!!!");
    });
  });
</script>
<div id="edit_div">
<input type="checkbox" value="mycheck" name="mycheck"/>
....
```

Answer (score 0):

The `document.ready` event which you've wrapped your function in only gets called when the page is first loaded.

You could try taking the function out of the `document.ready` wrapper and placing the whole `script` tag at the end of the markup you're sending from your controller.

Comment: sadly this does not work, still no access to jquery. I'll try to move the function to the calling page but maybe it will be invisible to the dialog-function?

Comment: No, the function needs to run after your dialog box has been populated otherwise jQuery won't find the checkbox to attach the click handler to.